# Need to find the time of the last boot from a .cpp using linux ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, time

So I am very new to C++ and Linux and i need to find the time of the last boot from a c++ file. I have been using /proc files for the other info. **I am not looking for up time.**

I was trying to find a way to execute the "last reboot" command from my .cpp file but i cant figure this out. Is this possible, or is there a way to find the current time so i can subtract up time form the current?

Very lost...

This is homework by the way, but i have completed every other section and am just tied up on this one small part.

Also i have goggled for hours and just cant find a way... Am i misinterpreting something and its more simple then I am making it?

Just need **the time of the last system boot**

Thanks!

Comment: You can't subtract "uptime" from the current time?

Comment: +1 for stating it is homework and being honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with the /var/log/syslog   not perfect since it will only work for 5 weeks but i think its sufficient for my assignment  thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

Get the current time using [time (2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) and subtract the number of seconds since boot that you get from [sysinfo (2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sysinfo).

If you want the result in a nice, displayable format, use [ctime (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime) to turn it into a date/time string.